# Startup point for Symbian/embedded programming learning

Tags: embedded, symbian

I have good knowledge on C++ (not C) and recently bought a Symbian-based phone.
This gave me reasons to start learning on how to program this beast.

I have searched for Symbian programming tutorials but there is so much knowledge that it is hard to choose best for startup.

So I'm asking for hints, tips on where to start embedded/Symbian programming learning that would give me a kick-start in this topic; especially if you have this knowledge yourself.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will merely point out a few resources that I used when I embarked on the journey to become a Symbian Developer.

1. The [Learning Centre](http://developer.symbian.com/main/learning/) at Symbian Developer portal. There are all manners of documents, whitepapers, and tutorials there to get you up to speed with Symbian internals and application development. Also, you will eventually have to get the Symbian SDKs and dev tools from there.
2. [Forum Nokia](http://www.forum.nokia.com/)
3. [NewLC.com](http://www.newlc.com/) A thriving and very helpful community of Symbian developers. It is updated sufficiently often.
4. I am glad to have got the book [Accredited Symbian Developer Primer](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Accredited-Symbian-Developer-Primer-Fundamentals/dp/0470058277). Even though it does not delve into the depths of anything, in an amazingly small space it explains some of the most fundamental and most difficult to grasp concepts very brilliantly.

Answer (score 3):

Symbian developer site has been renewed since the launch of Symbian Foundation and is now in public beta: https://developer.symbian.org/

Answer (score 2):

There's this website: http://www.symbiantutorial.org that has a nice review of the Symbian C++. If you want to go on with C++, that's the starting point I believe.

You could also try out the [PyS60](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pys60), it's a Python for Symbian 60 devices, quite neat and nice to start.

Comment: Symbiantutorial.org - 2005?. Quite outdated but nonetheless a remarkable source. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are the exact intended audience for a recent Symbian Press book :
http://www.quickrecipesonsymbianos.com

It is meant as an introduction into the Symbian development ecosystem for developers who haven't targetted mobile phones before. It is supposed to guide you step by step during the first two weeks of your learning curve and show you where to go after that.

Sorry for the shameless plug, it's just that you're exactly describing what this book was written for. Hopefully, it will help do just what you asked.